# change Qt font to native system default font

Tags: macos, qt

In my native Cocoa app (on OSX 10.10), buttons look like this:

[image: native OSX]

In Qt (4.8.6), buttons look like this:

[image: Qt]

As you see, the font is a different one, and the text is not centered vertically.

How can I let use Qt the system default font, and how can I vertically center the text in the buttons?
(The Qt font is the same (wrong) one in all other widgets too, so buttons are just an example.)

---

Via [this](http://successfulsoftware.net/2013/10/23/fixing-qt-4-for-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks/), [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32789) and [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40833):

I have added this code, which somewhat fixes it (it's centered correctly now), I think the font is a different one then before, but still not the correct one.

```
#ifdef Q_OS_MACX
    // fix OSX 10.9 font
    // http://successfulsoftware.net/2013/10/23/fixing-qt-4-for-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks/
    // https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32789
    QFont::insertSubstitution(".Lucida Grande UI", "Lucida Grande");
    // fix OSX 10.10 font
    // https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40833
    QFont::insertSubstitution(".Helvetica Neue DeskInterface", "Helvetica Neue");
#endif
```

Now, it looks like this:

[image: qt-with-fix]

I also tried Qt 5.3.2, but there is no difference:

[image: qt5]

Comment: http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_does_qt_pick_a_font_for_the_application ... are you sure that Cocoa uses the system default font?

Comment: @msrd0: As you see, it does not. That is my question. How do I fix that?

Comment: I thought your question was how to make that using Qt and not how to do that using Cocoa?

Comment: @msrd0: Yes exactly. Cocoa by default use the system default font. Qt by default does not use the system default font. How can I make Qt use the system default font?

Comment: On my system Qt uses the systems default font, probably because KDE is written in Qt

Comment: @msrd0: Well, it does not on mine. That's my question. How can I fix that?

Comment: @msrd0 The application's intended users are running Finder and the rest of the OS X desktop, not KDE Plasma.